# jquery force style over css file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div inside a div.. working more like a drop menu.
my problem is when I click on the `#two` div. I want to disappear.

so I used jquery. and I used `.hide()` or `.slideUp()`.

but when any of them is used then I tried I hover over #one, #two never appear again?

I checked why. I found out jquery add attribute to div#two as `style="display:none"`. and css will not override that.

and if I add in css: to `display: block !important;`. jquery will not hide #two when is clicked.

what is the middle ground to this. if I re-triggered the class which hide #two it will not work. because the mouse still over #one.

```
<div id="one">
    <span>Main</span>
    <div id="two">Sub</div>
</div>
```

css will be:

```
#one{
    position: relative;
}

#two {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#one:hover #two {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Need to explain full expected behavior and what click on `#two` does in full (or should do). See [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are linking your js actions badly. Plus the best practice is not to mingle the use of `.show()` and `.hide()` with display in css. Choose your solution (js vs css) and stick to it.

Delete your:

```
#one:hover #two {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the needed js:

```
$('#one span').click(function(){
    $('#two').show();
})

$('#two').click(function(){
    $('#two').hide();
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q27tu1cg/

Comment: but if user clicked away it will not hide #two, forcing the use to clicked on #two